# How can a bar chart be created in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to create a bar P-state chart in Matlab

the function of `P_state` is

```
((1-rho)*(rho.^n))*(100);
```

`n` is 0 to 20

I have tried this but it is just giving me a red screen

```
   for n = 0:20
       P_state = ((1-rho)*(rho.^n))*(100);
   end
   bar(P_state,'r')
```

What am I doing wrong? And how can I generate the bar chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made simple mistake: your `P_state` isn't an array. So you calculate new value of it at each iteration and rewrite it in `P_state`. At last step you have only last value, what is why you have just an red screen.

You just need to add an index to your `P_state` variable:

```
for n = 0:20
    P_state(n+1) = ((1-rho)*(rho.^n))*(100);
end
bar(P_state,'r')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you my friend